# Isobaric process confusion

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

How does the pressure remains constant during isobaric expansion/compression despite of giving/taking heat to/from the system? I am having a confusion to understand. How does this process actually take place?

Answer (score 3):

Isobaric processes usually occur when a system is put in contact with a pressure reservoir, i.e. a system with a given pressure that imposes its pressure on all the other systems in contact with it. A common example of pressure reservoir is the Earth atmosphere: if you put your system in contact with the atmosphere it will acquire its pressure ($1$ atm); moreover the Earth atmosphere is so large compared to usual systems that any process that occur in the system will not change the atmosphere pressure. that's the general idea on how a pressure reservoir can always keep its pressure constant.

Remember that thermodynamics considers usually quasi-static processes, for which the system remains in equilibrium with the reservoir for the whole process. Thus even if the systems can expand or exchange heat, its pressure will always remain equal to that of the reservoir and thus constant.